# Compilation error when pip3 install scipy

Tags: python, scipy, ubuntu-14.04

I need to install `scipy`. However, after about 5-7minutes of compilation time I am getting the follwing error on Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS:

```
sudo pip3 install scipy
...
error: Command "x86_64-linux-gnu-g++ -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS=1 -Iscipy/sparse/sparsetools -I/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/numpy/core/include -I/usr/include/python3.4m -c scipy/sparse/sparsetools/csc.cxx -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/scipy/sparse/sparsetools/csc.o" failed with exit status 4

In file included from /usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/ndarraytypes.h:1777:0,

                 from /usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/ndarrayobject.h:18,

                 from scipy/sparse/sparsetools/sparsetools.h:5,

                 from scipy/sparse/sparsetools/csc.cxx:4:

/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/npy_1_7_deprecated_api.h:15:2: warning: #warning "Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it by " "#defining NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API NPY_1_7_API_VERSION" [-Wcpp]

 #warning "Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it by " \

  ^

x86_64-linux-gnu-g++: internal compiler error: Killed (program cc1plus)

Please submit a full bug report,

with preprocessed source if appropriate.

See <file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-4.8/README.Bugs> for instructions.

----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
Command /usr/bin/python3 -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip_build_root/scipy/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-e3q7ek8f-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip_build_root/scipy
Storing debug log for failure in /home/ubuntu/.pip/pip.log
```

Does anybody have an idea how to fix this?

Comment: Do you have numpy installed already?

Comment: Yes, numpy is installed

Comment: Try pip3 install -U numpy and rerun pip3 install scipy afterwards

Comment: `sudo pip3 install -U numpy` yields:
`Requirement already up-to-date: numpy in /usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages
Cleaning up...`. I do not think that that will have an effect

Answer (score 1):

It seems your numpy was installed using the distro package manager (i.e. by running `apt-get install python3-numpy`) since the numpy package is in the `dist-packages` directory of your python libs. Why don't you install scipy this way too? You can just run

`sudo apt-get install python3-scipy`

If you want to use `pip`, I suggest installing packages in [`virtualenv`](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/) instances (or, even better, [`virtualenvwrapper`](https://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)) so that you avoid such conflicts. Otherwise, you should be using a systemwide version of pip, rather than a user installed one (the output says your pip belongs to user `ubuntu`), so you could first install it using `apt-get` and then make sure to use this new pip to install scipy.

Comment: No, I did use pip3 to install numpy

Comment: are you using the same pip install for both?

Answer (score 0):

Installing `setuptools` made it work for me on ubuntu 14.04